# OpenCV thresholding unlike expected

Tags: java, opencv

I would like to preprocess a given picture  by thresholding it in order to then hand it over to Tesseract. I first did that using Gimp (2.8.16) and a fixed range of 130 – 255. When I then implemented it in OpenCV (3.1) using Java, I first forgot to call cvtColor resulting in a picture that still had some colors in it (these areas were white in Gimp). Besides that, the picture was as expected. However, when I implemented the corresponding call, I got a picture that was different to the one I would have expected. It seems that the areas that were colored previously are now black while the remaining picture is similar to the one I created with Gimp.

Is there anything that I am missing to create a more similar output?

The reason I am asking this question is that, unfortunately, Tesseract (with psm 6) creates quite different results for the two images:

- for the one created in Gimp: "2011 1 L 0006"
- for the second one created with OpenCV: "2011ÔÇö] L 0 0006 1"

Here is the code that I used:

```
Mat thres = new Mat();
Mat tmp = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // tmp = src.clone(); in my first attempt
Imgproc.threshold(tmp, thres, 130, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("output.jpg", thres);
```

Here are the pictures:

Given picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOeMw.jpg]

Picture created with Gimp:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox8g9.jpg]

First result using OpenCV:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHLZN.jpg]

Second result using OpenCV:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTlw3.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, You are doing thresholding on color image (tmp = src.clone() creates another copy of src which is a color image). So you  are getting result like that and in the second case, you are first converting to grayscale and then thresholding which gives a better result. Thresholding is good on gray scale images.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 

I would like to create it based on the color image. However, I do not want the colored parts in the resulting image but only the black parts (like the font which appears to be mostly black). What would I have to do additionally to get to that?

Comment: You can iterate through the image and check for pixel values in three channels, keep the same value if it is 0 or 255 in all three channels or else replace with 0, which will turn these color values to black.